# How to make different type of inputs(file, text) work together

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a form with 2 types of image input(from file and from URL). I need to use image from the last changed input. For this I made an additional invisible input field "imgTempURL" , which fills with image's url(or base64 string, if it's a file) when one of the input fields is changed.
For example, if I upload a file to the file input,"imgTempURL" value changes to base64 string. If I fill the URL field value, "imgTempURL" value changes to the URL field value. Then I press a button and "imgTempURL" value is sent to the server. That how it works.
**The problem is that "imgTempURL" isn't filled with new base64 string, if I try to upload a file after I filled URL input field - it remains with the same old url link value.**

Here's the part of HTML:

```
<input type="text" id="imgTempUrl"/> <--made it visible to see its value-->
<cfform id="form">
    Use file    
    <input type="file" id="imgUp" accept=".jpg"> 
    or URL 
    <input type="text" name="url" id="url" size="20"  
              onkeyup="document.getElementById('imgTempUrl').value=this.value;">  
    <input type="Submit" class="" value="Generate" id="generate">
</cfform>
```

I get base64 string with in this function:

```
$(function(){
    $('#imgUp').change(function(){
        imgUp = document.getElementById('imgUp');
        if(imgUp.files && imgUp.files[0]){
            var reader = new FileReader();
            reader.onload = function(e){
            $('#imgTempUrl')
                .attr('value', e.target.result);
            };
            reader.readAsDataURL(imgUp.files[0]);
        }
    });
});
```

How can I solve this problem?
Is there something I should know about working with file inputs and their behavior?

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`$('#imgTempUrl').attr('value',e.target.result);`  This is not the way to set value of an input text. You should use `.val()` method to set the value.

```js
$(function(){
    $('#imgUp').change(function(){
        imgUp = document.getElementById('imgUp');
        if(imgUp.files && imgUp.files[0]){
            var reader = new FileReader();
            reader.onload = function(e){
            $('#imgTempUrl').val(e.target.result);
            };
            reader.readAsDataURL(imgUp.files[0]);
        }
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" id="imgTempUrl"/> <--made it visible to see its value--><br>
<cfform id="form">
    Use file    
    <input type="file" id="imgUp" accept=".jpg"> <br>
    or URL 
    <input type="text" name="url" id="url" size="20"  
              onkeyup="document.getElementById('imgTempUrl').value=this.value;">  
    <input type="Submit" class="" value="Generate" id="generate">
</cfform>
```

Comment: Thank you very much! You saved my day!